# How to align the bottom of arrays with blkarray and subcaption

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption, blkarray

I want to align the bottom of two arrays placed side by side.

I can see that the problem comes from the extra spacing between the right array and the legend and that comes from the \\ of line 3, but these \\ are mandatory with the *block* environment (even in the last line) . Does anyone see a trick to fix the problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\fbox{
            $\left[
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                10  &20     &30\\
                15  &25     &35\\
                11  &22     &33\\
            \end{tabular}
        \right]$
        %}
        \caption{Left array}
        \label{tab:leftarray}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\fbox{
            \begin{blockarray}[b]{c ccc}
                    &Column 1 &Column 2 &Column 3\\
                \begin{block}{r [ccc]}
                    Line 1  &10&20&30\\
                    Line 2  &15&25&35\\
                    Line 3  &11&22&33\\
                \end{block}
            \end{blockarray}
        %}
        \caption{Right array}
        \label{tab:rightarray}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{How to align the bottom of arrays}
    \label{tab:HowHowHow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack your way by adding `\\[-1em]` right after `\end{blockarray}` of the right array. However, this will not get you a *perfect* alignment overall because the square brackets of the left array are slightly longer than the right array.

The more complete fix would be to not use a `tabular` environment but a `blockarray` environment without the additional row and column. Also, you have `>{\enskip}` and `<{\enskip}` (before the start/after the end of a cell, insert whatever is in `{...}`) added in the block argument to add padding between the cells and the square brackets.

The imprecise alignment of the captions is fixed by assigning the appropriate `subtable` widths. Note that removing  `\rule{...}{0.4pt}` will eliminate the `Overfull \hbox` warning.

[image: Output]

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
     \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
        \centering
         \fbox{
            \begin{blockarray}[b]{ccc}
                \begin{block}{[>{\enskip}ccc<{\enskip}]}
                    10&20&30\\
                    15&25&35\\
                    11&22&33\\
                \end{block}
            \end{blockarray}
        }
        \hbox{\rule{1.17\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
        \caption{Left array}
        \label{tab:leftarray}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
        \centering
        \fbox{
            \begin{blockarray}[b]{c ccc}
                    &Column 1 &Column 2 &Column 3\\
                \begin{block}{r [ccc]}
                    Line 1  &10&20&30\\
                    Line 2  &15&25&35\\
                    Line 3  &11&22&33\\
                \end{block}
            \end{blockarray}
        }
        \hbox{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
        \caption{Right array}
        \label{tab:rightarray}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{The bottom arrays are aligned}
    \label{tab:HowHowHow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to take the same environment for both arrays, even if the first one doesn't have titles for the rows and columns. Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subtable}[b]{.28\textwidth}
  \centering
  $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[baseline=b]
    10  &20     &30\\
    15  &25     &35\\
    11  &22     &33\\
    11  &22     &33\\
  \end{bNiceMatrix}$

  \caption{Left array}
  \label{tab:leftarray}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{.68\textwidth}
  \centering
  $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,baseline=b]
    &\text{Column 1} & \text{Column 2} & \text{Column 3} \\
    \text{Line 1}  &10&20&30\\
    \text{Line 2}  &15&25&35\\
    \text{Line 3}  &11&22&33\\
  \end{bNiceMatrix}$

  \caption{Right array}
  \label{tab:rightarray}
\end{subtable}

\caption{How to align the bottom of arrays}
\label{tab:HowHowHow}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\hspace*{\fill}%
\subcaptionbox{Left array\label{tab:leftarray2}}{%
  $\begin{bmatrix}
    10  &20     &30\\
    15  &25     &35\\
    11  &22     &33\\
    11  &22     &33\\
  \end{bmatrix}$%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Right array\label{tab:rightarray2}}{%
  $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
    &\text{Column 1} & \text{Column 2} & \text{Column 3} \\
    \text{Line 1}  &10&20&30\\
    \text{Line 2}  &15&25&35\\
    \text{Line 3}  &11&22&33\\
  \end{bNiceMatrix}$%
}\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{How to align the bottom of arrays}
\label{tab:HowHowHow2}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `\subcaptionbox` you don't need to worry about the width and the subcaptions will be automatically aligned.

[image]

Comment: I am using the 2019 version of texlive and the baseline and first-row options of nicematrix are not recognized.  I did however see in your 2nd solution (the one with \subcaptionbox) the similarity to \subfloat from the subfig package I was using before. I will explore your 2 suggestions more thoroughly when I update Texlive. thank you for your reply